# What's wrong with my Navbar menu refusing to fire onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, menu

I have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/apple-basket-styledcomponent-navbar-ubw67?file=/src/components/elements/SideMenu.jsx) with a Hamburger menu that refuse to let `onClick` work.

This image show the simple menu with the `Timeline` link
*(it's suppose to be text color white but Codesandbox refuses)*
Clicking the link does not fire the `onClick` it's like it's being blocket by another component.

[image]

I have tested to remove the Component `NavLinkPage` that is rendered at the same time and then my Menu works. It's like it's blocking even it's set to be off screen.

I have tried to set e.g. the `z-index` but with no luck the only think that works is removing the:

```
<NavLinkPage close={close} />..
```

The simple Menu is the Component:

```
<SideMenu close={close} />..
```

`NavLinkPage` are controlled by `@media (max-width: 1098px)..` and will show on large screens only.

here is CollapseMenu.jsx code with `NavLinkPage` and `NavLinkPage` :

```
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { useSpring, animated } from 'react-spring';
import useOnClickOutside from './UseOnClickOutside';
import NavLinkPage from './NavLinkPage';
import SideMenu from './SideMenu';

const CollapseMenu = props => {
    const { show, close } = props;
    const { open } = useSpring({ open: show ? 0 : 1 });

    const reference = useRef();
    useOnClickOutside(reference, close, 'burgerMenu');

    const escFunction = useCallback(
        event => {
            // only accept 27 if it's visible
            if (event.keyCode === 27 && show === true) {
                close();
            }
        },
        [close],
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', escFunction, false);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', escFunction, false);
        };
    }, [escFunction]);

    if (show === true) {
        return (
            <CollapseWrapper
                style={{
                    transform: open
                        .interpolate({
                            range: [0, 0.2, 0.3, 1],
                            output: [0, -20, 0, -200],
                        })
                        .interpolate(openValue => `translate3d(0, ${openValue}px, 0`),
                }}
            >
                <NavLinkPage close={close} />
                <SideMenu close={close} />
            </CollapseWrapper>
        );
    }
    return null;
};

export default CollapseMenu;

const CollapseWrapper = styled(animated.div)`
    background: #2d3436;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 100;
`;
```